# How can a disconnected TCP socket be reliably detected using MsgWaitForMultipleObjects?

Tags: python, windows, networking, twisted, reactor

Twisted includes [a reactor implemented on top of `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/internet/win32eventreactor.py).  Apparently the reactor has problems reliably noticing when a TCP connection ends, at least in the case where a peer sends some bytes and then quickly closes the connection.  What seems to happen is:

1. [The reactor calls `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` with some socket handles and `QS_ALLINPUT`.](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/internet/win32eventreactor.py#L186)
2. The call completes and indicates the handle for a socket in this state (that is, has bytes waiting to be read and has been closed by the peer) is active.
3. [The reactor dispatches this notification to the common TCP implementation.](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/internet/tcp.py#L443)
4. The TCP implementation reads the available bytes from the socket.  There are some, they get delivered to application code.
5. Control is returned to the reactor, which eventually calls `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` again.
6. `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` never again indicates that the handle is active.  The TCP implementation never gets to look at the socket again, so it can never detect that the connection is closed.

This makes it appear as though `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` is an edge-triggered notification mechanism.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

```
Waits until one or all of the specified objects are in the signaled state
or the time-out interval elapses.
```

This doesn't sound like edge-triggering.  It sounds like level-triggering.

Is `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` actually edge-triggered?  Or is it level-triggered and this misbehavior is caused by some other aspect of its behavior?

*Addendum* [The MSDN docs for WSAEventSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains what's going on here a bit more, including pointing out that `FD_CLOSE` is basically a one-off event.  After its signaled once, you'll never get it again.  This goes some way towards explaining why Twisted has this problem.  I'm still interested to hear how to effectively use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` given this limitation, though.

Comment: I can't really follow the code, but nowhere is it calling WSAEnumNetworkEvents() to determine which network events actually occurred.  I believe you are right in that FD_CLOSE is a one-shot deal, so you have to set a flag somewhere to let yourself know the connection has been closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `WSAEventSelect` and differentiate activities, you need to call `WSAEnumNetworkEvents`.  Make sure you're processing each event that was reported, not just the first.

`WSAAsyncSelect` makes it easy to determine the cause, and is often used together with `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`.

So you might use `WSAAsyncSelect` instead of `WSAEventSelect`.

Also, I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the difference between edge-triggered and level-triggered.  Your reasoning seems to be more related to auto-reset vs manual-reset events.

Comment: Thanks.  `WSAAsyncSelect` looks interesting.  From its documentation, it seems multiple Events might not be necessary, since "FD_CLOSE is not delivered until all pending data has been read".  Do you think that guarantee is sufficient to make a one-Event approach workable?  Also, re edge- and level-triggering, I wrote those comments before I knew that resetting was something that happened to some events; in the light of resetting, the edge and level terminology doesn't seem applicable at all.  Would you agree with that?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: The next sentence is "An application should check for remaining data upon receipt of FD_CLOSE to avoid any possibility of losing data.", which seems to contradict the one before.  But it sounds like your problem isn't determining whether to read data after close, it's telling the difference between "socket closed" and "data in buffer" to begin with.

Comment: You can only associate a single event object with a socket via WSAEventSelect, but that event object can notify you of multiple (types of) network events.  Typically you only care about FD_CONNECT/FD_ACCEPT, FD_READ, and FD_CLOSE.

Comment: @Luke: But how do you find which network event(s) set the kernel event?  Ahh, `WSAEnumNetworkEvents` is the missing piece.

Comment: WSAEventSelect/WSAEnumNetworkEvents combination seems to be a winner.  WSAAsyncSelect ends up not being very useful since I don't have a Window.  Thanks!